# How to chain API requests using Kotlin Flow

Tags: android, kotlin, reactive-programming, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Based on a list of ids I need to retrieve a list of users with detailed informaiton of each user. Below a simplification of my models and API;

```
data class UserDTO(val id: String)
data class PetDTO(val name: String)

interface Api {
  suspend fun users(): List<UserDTO>
  suspend fun pets(userId: String): List<PetDTO>
}

data class User(
  val id: String,
  val pets: List<Pet>
)

data class Pet(val name: String)

class UsersRepository(api: Api) {
  val users: Flow<List<User>> = TODO()
}
```

In RxJava I would do something like this:

```
val users: Observable<List<User>> = api.users()
  .flatMapIterable { it }
  .concatMap { userDto ->
    api.pets(userDto.id)
      .map { petsListDto ->
        User(userDto.id, petsListDto.map { Pet(it.name) })
      }
  }.toList()
```

How can I implement `UsersRepository` and return the list of `User`s using Kotlin Flow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class UsersRepository(api: Api) {
    val users: Flow<List<User>> = flow {
        val usersWithPets = api.users().map { userDto ->
            val pets = api.pets(userDto.id).map { petsListDto ->
                Pet(petsListDto.name)
            }
            User(userDto.id, pets)
        }
        emit(usersWithPets)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.